# Can I access a submodule that is using the same name as an import?

Tags: python, import

Consider this import:

```
from .scale_shape import scale_shape
```

https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/blob/cbc50afaccb82e6f062034139cfc190fc49f81c5/plotnine/scales/__init__.py#L56-L59

Do I have any chance of accessing (reading and ideally, writing) the `shapes` variable here?
https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/blob/cbc50afaccb82e6f062034139cfc190fc49f81c5/plotnine/scales/scale_shape.py#L11-L25

Any time I try to access `plotnine.scales.scale_shape`, I end up with the class, not the submodule, and while `shapes` is part of the submodule, it's not a member of the class. Is there another way to access `.scale_shape` instead of `scale_shape` in `plotnine.shapes`?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you said `plotnine.shapes.scale_shape` did you mean `plotnine.scales.scale_shape`?

Comment: The thing you're trying to poke is not part of plotnine's public API. You really shouldn't be poking it.

Comment: @Kemp yes, thanks!

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica consider this a Python learning exercise for me. Primarily, this question is about *if* this is possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe that if the `__init__.py` in `scales` imports `scale_shape.scale_shape` as `scale_shape` then you no longer have access to the module `scale_shape`.